Load spring boot bean conditionally from database value, not from property file
I am using rabbitMQ in my application having configured exchange as follows:
@Bean
DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("my.controller.exchange", true, false);
}

However, I want to handle based on a database value like:
@Bean
@Condition("CREATE".equals("select value from config where key ='ETL'"))
DirectExchange exchange() {
    return new DirectExchange("my.controller.exchange", true, false);
}

Is there a way to dynamically load a bean like this?

You will have to write your own @Condiiton rule.

@Antoniossss any hint will be appreciated

Here you go buddy, iv googled it for you https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations#defining-custom-conditions

Use Apache Commons Configuration, define a JDBC configuration source. The Apache Commons Configuration has integration for Spring (Boot) as well just exposing properties as regular properties. You can then use a regular @ConditionalOnProperty without caring where that property comes from.

If you don't want to use Apache Commons Configuration, the easiest is to write a JdbcPropertySource which retrieves properties from a database and expose that as a PropertySource using an EnvironmentPostProcessor. It can be a bit fiddly to setup as you might need a dedicated DataSource for it using the spring.datasource.url properties or other dedicated ones.

We can create bean after application is ready. Check for ApplicationReadyEvent EventListener.
Sample
Controller:
Set DirectExchange object creation is lazy.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    private final CustomerMapper customerMapper;
    private final DirectExchange directExchange;

    public CustomerController (CustomerRepository customerRepository, CustomerMapper customerMapper,@Lazy DirectExchange directExchange) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.customerMapper = customerMapper;
        this.directExchange = directExchange;
    }
// other methods

}

Config:
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

   @Autowired
    private GenericApplicationContext context;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void onApplicationReady() {
        ConfigRepository configRepository = context.getBean(ConfigRepository.class);
        List<DBConfig> values = configRepository.findByKeyAndValue("ETL", "CREATE");

        if(!values.isEmpty() ) {
            context.registerBean(DirectExchange.class, () -> new DirectExchange("my.controller.exchange", true, false));
         }
    }
}

Repository:
@Repository
public interface ConfigRepository extends CrudRepository<DBConfig, Integer>{
    List<DBConfig> findByKeyAndValue(String key, String value);
}


I think you can start by defining a bean (ConfigFromDb) that depends on the DataSource. Use @PostConstruct within the bean to query the database and store the results in the bean's field.
Then, your dynamic bean can depend on ConfigFromDb(@DependesOn("configFromDb")), and you can use @ConditionalOnExpression to evaluate and compare the properties stored in ConfigFromDb. This way, the dynamic bean may will conditionally load based on the database query results.
Additionally, perhaps org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean is what you're really looking for? It allows you to create beans dynamically, providing more flexibility in how beans are instantiated and managed in the Spring container

That won't work as the conditional rules are evaluated before that, hence you run into issues with ordering even with the @DependsOn.

@DependsOn is applied to the external class that declares the method creating the bean.

The @DependsOn is evaluated later in the process. When conditional expression are being resolved that doesn't apply yet, so it won't work.

That's odd. I'm not entirely sure where the subtle difference lies, but when I used JDK 23 and Spring Boot 2.4.1, I did get the expected result.
